# .htaccess not always loading

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, osx-mountain-lion, slim

Ok so i recently upgraded my imac to mountain lion osx (10.8) from Lion. I have been using default apache setup with vhosts and the likes for php development, since upgrading the install changed a lot of settings to my httpd.conf file.

Currently i have two projects on the go one using a CakePHP setup and the other using SlimFramework both php frameworks with an .htaccess file.

Im having a few issues where the cakephp htaccess loads and works as expected but the slimframework one does not.  BOTH of these worked on Lion and i am very confused as to why they are being treated differently.

mod_rewrite module is loaded, it is enabled, and my AllowOverides is set to ALL.  What would be causing the SlimFramework file not to load?

Comment: Are you sure it's being ignored? Can you put some gibberish in the htaccess file and try to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after multiple hours of googling i came across this blog post petercompernolle.com/2012/07/26/fixing-httpdconf-in-osx-mountainlion

It describes the issues and fixes invloved in fixing apache after a mountain lion upgrade including the HTAccess issues you may be experiencing.

Excerpt taking from article

> And then several hours later, I figured it out. It's no longer stored at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. For some reason, Apple has changed something that's worked for a long time, and instead created a whole bunch of files in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites. There's a .conf file for anything on port 80, another .conf file for the site I created in Server.app, and a whole bunch of other backups made for every change I made in Server.app.